# Members present and voting?

Tags: bylaw

I'm working on bylaws for an organization and I'm having a hard time parsing out the details of the term "members present and voting" as described in various sections of *Roberts Rules of Order, Newly Revised*.

I do understand the general purpose in that it prevents abstentions from counting as negative votes. I wonder, though, if it could have unintended consequences.

Given a bylaws article which states:

> all issues to be voted on shall be decided by a simple majority of qualified members present and voting at the meeting in which the vote takes place, provided a quorum is present.

In an extreme hypothetical situation: at a meeting where there is a quorum present, there are 50 members qualified to vote in attendance. An issue comes up for a vote, and 45 people abstain, 3 vote yes, 2 vote no.

Would this pass 3 to 2, or is there some overriding part of "majority present and voting" that I am just not understanding?

Comment: This is over-complicated. *"The motion passes if and only if (a) the majority of votes cast are in favour of the motion, and (b) the total number of votes cast is not less than [quorum number]"* - this is unambiguous and does the job. I am presuming here if a vote is cast there is no additional need to be "present" (i.e. no sense that a vote can be cast without one being present but doesn't actually count towards a majority, only a quorum, because that would be daft).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> In an extreme hypothetical situation: at a meeting where there is a
> quorum present, there are 50 members qualified to vote in attendance.
> An issue comes up for a vote, and 45 people abstain, 3 vote yes, 2
> vote no.
>
> Would this pass 3 to 2, or is there some overriding part of "majority
> present and voting" that I am just not understanding?

The measure would pass 3-2. The words mean what they say. Quorum requirements prevent the small number of people voting from being unfair.

Comment: As an explanation: Per my understanding, a vote of abstaining is still a vote. The quorum rule has the intention of a couple of individuals setting up a meeting at a very unfortune time (that only they plus a few supporters can attend) and pass their ideas without any actual opposition getting a chance to vote. the 46 members in your example were there and had the option to oppose the voted item. They just didn't care. But that's not what this rule is supposed to address

Comment: No, you don't vote to abstain; rather you abstain, or decline to vote. "Present and voting" to me unambiguously excludes people who do not vote. As a tangent, I was briefly part of an organization with poorly written bylaws that a) only required a quorum to call a vote and b) required a majority of "permanent members present" to pass changes, which led several times to people walking out of the room after a vote was called.

Comment: @AndrewRay Can you elaborate on why the "walking out of the room" happened? Who did it and what did they gain by it?

Comment: @nanoman Walking out of the room means there's no quorum, which prevents any actions from being taken. Technically they're not against or abstaining on any particular vote, so it affects the optics.

Comment: @Barmar That didn't make sense to me because Andrew said that the bylaws "only required a quorum to call a vote" and that people walked out "**after** a vote was called". So if the vote had already been called, the phase where a quorum was required was already over. I'm still confused whether the people walking out were preventing the vote from happening, or whether the vote did happen (i.e., actions *were* being taken) and their goal was just to have the effect of abstaining without officially abstaining.

Comment: @nanoman He might not be describing the bylaws or order of actions precisely. Maybe the bylaws required the quorum to take the vote, or people walked out when they knew a vote was about to be called (because of the agenda).

Comment: @AndrewRay Can you clarify, since both Barmar and I seem unable to precisely understand the scenario you described?

Comment: They were not walking out to cancel the vote because of quorum. They were walking out so that they didn't count as present during the vote. So somebody would move to take a vote, that would get seconded, they would count the quorum, then people would leave, and they would take the vote and recount. It was the only functional way to abstain because the procedural rules were messed up.

Answer (score 4):

### It would pass

However, there is a slight ambiguity there that you are better off eliminating. Assume the dispute comes up 50 years from now when you and everyone else who wrote the rules are long gone: how can you write it so it's crystal clear? Putting in your example might be a way of doing that.

Comment: There's no ambiguity, though. This is just a case of someone looking at an unambiguous clause and saying "wait, really?" People can say "wait, really?" about anything. The fact that someone can say "wait, really?" about something doesn't make it ambiguous.

Comment: There may sometimes be value in explicitly stating the logical consequences of unambiguous rules, especially when the logic is tricky or when it can be hard to find all the rules that apply, but I don't know if embedding an explicit example for this in the bylaws would be worth the bloat.

Answer (score 0):

The largest ambiguity is "and voting".

That might mean the majority of those who chose to vote on this question (i.e. are there more 'aye's than 'nay's), which matches your example.

It also might mean a majority of the members present who currently have voting privileges. For example, in an HOA it's common to not allow members with outstanding debts to vote. In that case, you would look instead at the number of members present with voting privileges and check whether the 'aye's are more than 50% of the total ('nay' is the same as abstaining in this case). In this case, you should also check your quorum definition.

In either case, you should define "majority". Some common definitions are "greater than 50%" or "50% plus one vote".

Comment: "50% plus one vote" -- so if three people are voting. the measure has to get 2.5 votes or more to pass? "majority" has a clear meaning.

Comment: @PBJ yes. If you look around, you'll see that's a very common rule.

Comment: 50% plus one is not good policy. It means that with >100 voting and an odd number, you need a two vote majority. So 51-50 would fail.

Comment: @fectin "50%+1" is a very common but incorrect definition of "majority."  There should be no need to define majority; before the 50%+1 idiocy started, it was completely unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you specify that for a measure to pass, it must satisfy two criteria:

1. The absolute number of votes cast in favor must be sufficient to represent a quorum even if everyone who did not favor the measure were to leave.
2. The number of votes cast in favor of the measure must exceed the number of votes cast against it.

Writing the rules in this fashion would make it clear that someone who was present but cast a recorded abstention or abstained from casting a recorded vote would not contribute to a measure's satisfying the first criterion, but would not interfere with its satisfying the second.

Comment: Such a rule would nmean that at a meeting where a bse quorum is present, a measure must have unanimous support to pass. This would be a quite unusual rule, and possibly unworkable. It is surely not what Robert's Rules intends.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: Does it make sense to say that the minimum number of people N who would have to favor some action to bring it about will be able to do so if N-1 additional people are present and oppose it, but the minimum number of supporters who would be required if nobody opposed to the measure shows up would be 2N-1?  In many cases, it makes sense to allow some kinds of business to be conducted with fewer members present than would be needed for others, and so the number of votes needed to pass a measure need not meet the highest quorum thresholds, but I don't think it makes sense to...

Comment: ...say that a measure can be passed if 26% of a group's membership vote for it while 25% vote against it, but not if 49% of the group's membership are present and vote for it while nobody who is opposed shows up.  Saying that certain kinds of measures may be passed with 34% of the membership being present and voting for them, even if those are the only people who show up, but no such measures can pass without the approval of a third of the membership even if 51% of the membership shows up seems safer.

Comment: the usual rule is that there is some quorum providio. This may be for a fixed percentage of the body, or for a fixed number of members present. This may be for a majority of the membership (as it is in Congress) or for a significantly smaller number. Without a quorum, nothing can be done. If a quorum is present, the majority (anything more than half, so 2-1or 3-2 is a majority) of those present and voting, not abstaining, carries any issue. Occasionally some special kinds of decision require a super-majority or super-quorum, but that is usually reserved for rare issues. [...]

Comment: [...] That is what Robert's rules provides. A groupm may choose a diferent rule, of course. But I think the usual rule works well for most groups, and is simpler to write nd sapply than the sort of rule you suggest.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: So what do the rules say happens if N people are required for a quorum, N-1 people are present and favor an action, one person is present and opposes it, and that person leaves just as a vote is about to be called?  One of the main purposes of having a quorum requirement is to set a lower threshold on the number of people who must favor a binding action in order to effect it.  I've read some group bylaws written essentially as I described (though with a specified fraction of the membership at large, e.g. 1/3 being required to approve an action) and they didn't seem confusing.

Comment: Under Robert's rules, if a quorum is nor present during the vote, the vote is treated as if it never occurred. Under those rules, if 50 people are present, but 45 abstain, a 3-2 vote carries the motion. Different groups use different rules. It is possible, but IME less usual, to specify a minimum amount of support for a motion to pass. Such rules should IMO be written as clearly and plainly as possible, with no ambiguities.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: Besides, what's most important is to recognize that no single set of bylaws can possibly be optimal for every organization.  If many group members will have outside commitments that limit their ability to attend meetings, but the group has some factions that may try to pass measures that would be opposed by a vast majority of the group at large, the approach I described may offer a better balance than approaches where approval only depends upon having a measure being favored by a majority of those present.  There's nothing magical about RROO.

Comment: True. Another measure often taken is to require that a detailed agenda be sent to all members well in advance, and require a super-majority or an enlarged quorum to take up anything not on the agenda, or even forbid such off-agenda items from being voted on. Yet another is to require measures to be passed at two different meetings to avoid the possibility of a single packed meeting. There are many possible options.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: Another approach would be to say that a vote which is taken with some fraction P lower than some threshold M present would only count if the winning or losing margin was at least M-P.  If M was 2/3, then a vote could pass with just over 1/3 of the membership voting for it (since it would win even if the imputed just-under-1/3 of the membership had voted against it), or be defeated with 1/3 of the membership voting against it (since it would fail even if the imputed 1/3 voted for it), but if neither scenario applies the measure would remain open.